# How to show this spinor identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, spinors

This is from page 59 of Peskin, Schroeder. Let $u^s(p)= \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\xi^s \\\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma}\xi^s} \end{pmatrix}$. On page 59 they claim that $u^s(\Lambda^{-1}p) = \Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}}^{-1}u^s(p)$, where $\Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}} = \exp(-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu})$ is the spinor representation of the Lorentz group. How to prove this relation?

Comment: You should probably use the series expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: I still don't get it?

Comment: This is how a spinor transforms under a Lorentz transformation. It is the spin 1/2 version of (2.37). See also the bottom of page 42 that shows that this is how a spinor needs to transform for Lorentz invariance of the Dirac equation.

Comment: ok i get it now thanks